# Is an event called immediately after object initialization?

Tags: swift, delegates

Does an event procedure like `override init` exist but immediately after completion?

I'm hoping for something like `override init_completed()`

I need to perform functionality immediately *after* the object is fully initialized.

Comment: You could explicitly call that from `init`

Comment: just call inside `init`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. 
I've got multiple objects parent -> child -> child.
It's a crap shoot as to which one is actually 'instantiated' first.
I tested it with print. Also, I keep getting 'nil' indicating that it's not 'real' yet.
I have to run functionality in the child immediately AFTER the parent and child are initiated.

Is there no way to run code immediately AFTER the object has been instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call a method at the end of the `init()` method:

```
struct myObject {
    init() {
        // Other code
        otherMethod()
    }
}
```

If your object is a subclass of `UIView` and exists inside a `UIViewController` you can of course override the `viewDidLoad()` method of the view controller.

For an isolated `UIVIew`, either `awakeFromNib()` or `didLayoutSubviews()` will be called after the view loads. There is more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview).

Other useful information available at the [Swift documentation on initialisation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html).

Comment: viewDidLoad would be right I think, except that for both UIView subclass & UITextField subclass I'm getting that the function doesn't exist.

Comment: I have edited the question - individual `UIView`s do not have a `viewdidLoad()` method. You can use `awakeFromNib()` or `didLayoutSubviews()` as a workaround.